# How i check existence of file and directory in ApplicationDocumentsDirectory before write it?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

I have the following code,
Am I trying to check if a path exists?
If the path already exists, write to the file.
I'm having trouble. please help me. tks all.

```
       Future<String> get _logcalPath async {
           final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
           return directory.path; // home/directory/
        }



    Future<File> get _localFile async {
        final path  = await _logcalPath;
        return File('$path/LOG.txt'); // home/directory/log.txt
   }



    Future<File> writeLog(String pdfData) async {

      final file = await _localFile;
      //write to file
      var sink = file.openWrite(mode: FileMode.append);
      file.writeAsString( "OPERATION" + pdfData.toString());
      await sink.flush();
      await sink.close();
      return file;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`File` has a method `exists()` which returns a `Future<bool>`. Use that to check whether the file/path exists.

```dart
Future<File> writeLog(String pdfData) async {
  final file = await _localFile;
  final fileExists = await file.exists();

  if(!fileExists) await file.create(); // Create your file if it does not exists.

  //write to file
  var sink = file.openWrite(mode: FileMode.append);
  file.writeAsString("OPERATION" + pdfData.toString());
  await sink.flush();
  await sink.close();
  return file;
}
```

Comment: I believe there is also an existsSync() method which circumvents the need to await a result. Also something to note is that Directory has these options as well.

Comment: I tried to look like you, but maybe that doesn't work. Do you think there will be any other way?